# Failure to download large file on Android

Tags: android, download, httpurlconnection

I'm developping an app that downloads large files.
It has been working fine for the past year, but I just find out about a strange behaviour on a specific url.

Here's my code:

```
while (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer) > -1) {
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    downloadedBytes += bufferLength;
}
```

It seems that for that specific URL inputStream.read(buffer) is returning -1 in the middle of the download. If I restart the download it will do it again but at a different position.
There are no exception. Any idea what is going on server side ? Is the connection reseted ? Shouldn't I get an exception in that case ?

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't come from the server which stops the upload ?

Comment: Yes the file is 250Mb, and I am able to download 10, 15, 25Mb, it changes every time. But the same url works fine when downloaded from a web browser...

Comment: Are you downloading it in an `AsyncTask` or `Service` ?

Comment: an asynctask executed from a service, but it has nothing to do with it. My app has been working fine downloading 5K large files / day for the past year. There's something wrong with that specific server and I try to find out what it is in order to handle that case